# How to correctly set up Core Data Stack to the first view controller in iOS and Swift?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to use Core Data in my iOS app, which uses `UINavigationController` and the first view controller within it on storyboard. And then I want to pass over the `NSManagedObjectContext` and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` in the `AppDelegate.h` to the first view controller within `UINavigationController`. So I first wrote the following code (note that I also use `UISplitViewController`):

```
var splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
var navigationController: UINavigationController!
if splitViewController.viewControllers.count == 2 {
    navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[1] as UINavigationController
} else {
    navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as UINavigationController
}
var firstViewController = navigationController.topViewController
firstViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
```

However, the compiler says that `UIViewController` doesn't have such properties as `managedObjectContext`. But it's weird given that when I tried to log it by `println(firstViewController)`, it said it's an instance of `FirstViewController`, not `UIViewController`... But anyway, I changed it to the following by downcasting it:

```
var firstViewController = navigationController.topViewController as FirstViewController
```

However, then the build works properly, but it immediately is crashed by the error: `"Swift dynamic cast failed"` in the runtime.

So how can I pass over the `NSManagedObjectContext` (and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`) to the first view controller?

I use Xcode 6.1 Beta 2 and Swift in my iOS (iPad) application.

Answer (score 2):

You could check out how Core Data is used in https://github.com/Alecrim/AlecrimCoreData. It looks as if it is a well thought out Core Data library for Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a separate class for Core Data and use it for core data stuff. Here is an example class:

```
class CoreDataHelper {

// MARK: - Properties

    private lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count - 1] as NSURL
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel? = {
        if let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("YOUR_MODEL_NAME", withExtension: "momd") {
            return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
        } else {
            println("Error: can't create managed object model")
            return nil
        }
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        if let managedObjectModel = self.managedObjectModel {
            let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
            let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("YOUR_MODEL_NAME.sqlite")

            var error: NSError? = nil

            let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
            coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options, error: &error)


            if let error = error {
                println("Error: Can't add persistent store type to persistent store coordinate")
                return nil
            } else {
                return coordinator
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: Can't create persistant store coordinator. Because managed object model is not valid.")
            return nil
        }
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        if let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator {
            let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
            managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

            return managedObjectContext
        } else {
            println("Error: Can't create managed object context. Persistent store coordinator is not valid")
            return nil
        }
    }()
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I just created a Master-Detail Application in Xcode 6.0 and checked the include CoreData box. The code in the template does exactly what you want...

Your first block of code:

```
var firstViewController = navigationController.topViewController
firstViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
```

Doesn't work because at compile time, topViewController is a UIViewController, even if it is something more specific at runtime. That is why you need the cast.

As for why your downcast isn't working... Either `navigationController` is empty, or its `topViewController` is empty. More likely the former than the latter.

Try wrapping your last few lines in some `if let`s and see what happens:

```
if let nav = navigationController {
    if let firstViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? FirstViewController {
        firstViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
    }
    else {
        println("navigationController.topViewController is not a FirstViewController")
    }
}
else {
    println("navigationController is empty")
}
```

Comment: Both `navigationController` and `topViewController` are not empty, but it returned `navigationController.topViewController is not a FirstViewController`. So it failed to downcast `topViewController` to `FirstViewController`, but I'm not sure why.